# Error running Powershell script in Centos72 with powershell 6 installed

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script to delete a folder on a bunch of Windows hosts in our cluster.

It runs fine in the ISE and when running local from my laptop. however, I installed powershell on my Centos7.2 machine and when I try to run I get the following error

```
Join-Path : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "drive" is 
null. Change the value of argument "drive" to a non-null value.
At /home/user/powershell/delete_.file.ps1:11 char:20
+     $newfilepath = Join-Path "\\$computer" "$file"
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], 
PSArgumentNullException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At /home/user/powershell/delete_.file.ps1:12 char:19
+     if (test-path $newfilepath) {
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

here is the code to the script

```
$filelist = @("C$\.file")
$computers = Get-Content /home/user/powershell/sw_win.txt

foreach ($file in $filelist)
{
    foreach ($computer in $computers)
    {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Analysing $computers"

    $newfilepath = Join-Path "\\$computer" "$file"
    if (test-path $newfilepath) {
        Write-Host "$newfilepath Folder exists"
        try
        {
            Remove-Item $newfilepath -Force -recurse -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-host "Error while deleting $newfilepath on $computer. 
`n$($Error[0].Exception.Message)"

        }
            Write-Host "$newfilepath folder deleted"
    } else {
        Write-Information -MessageData "Path $newfilepath does not exist"
            }
    }
}
```

I think its because $computer is not set, but what doesn't make sense is it works fine using ISE.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: On line three between your variables and ForEach, `out-host` your variables so you can see what they contain. Those file paths look a little weird and you may need to name them explicitly.

Comment: There appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6629) (limitation?) in the handling of UNC paths on Linux systems.